# Gitlab runner building images even after removing all inbound rules and removing public IP on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, aws-security-group

I have and AWS ec-2 machine that runs the gitlab-runner. In gitlab I have enabled the private runner that I deployed on AWS ec2 instance and  disabled all the shared runners. I don't have a privately hosted gitlab. I am just using their free version. I wanted to only enable gitlab's ip to access the gitlab-runner on aws so I first removed all the inbound rules to deny all inbound connections and removed the elastic ip from that instance just to check if it fails but I was surprised to find out that it still builds the image. Am I missing something here ? because gitlab cannot talk to the gitlab-runner without a public ip. I am really baffled here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitLab runner does not require any inbound ports to be opened. The runner connects to the GitLab instance, not the other way around.

Comment: So does that mean the Gitlab runner checks/pulls the request to build images from gitlab and not the other way round ?

Comment: Yes. See https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-does-communicate-gitlab-runners/7553 and https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1230.

Comment: So then how does it receive a response when all the inbound traffic is blocked. You can only probe gitlab server but doesn't it need some kind of response ? I am sorry this sounds silly.

Comment: The same way you can visit stackoverlow.com without having inbound ports open. I don't know the technical details of the runner (whether it queries GitLab each minute or using a realtime connection (like websockets)) but it probes the master server (either gitlab.com or any other self hosted location).